# Webview crash on reload from menu click

Tags: android, webview

I am dealing with an error on an Android simple demo.I have my internet check routine and a webview with a reload call when i click a menu.Here is my code

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final int DIALOG_NONETWORK = 0;
    WebView mywebview=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);


        if(!Connection()){
            String data = "<html>"  +  
                    "<body><h1>NO INTERNET</h1></body>"  +  
                    "</html>";
            mywebview.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8"); 
            Log.v("INTERNET","NO");

        }else{
            mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com"); 
            Log.v("INTERNET","YES");

        }
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                String data = "<html>"  +  
                        "<body><h1>NO INTERNET</h1></body>"  +  
                        "</html>";
                mywebview.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8"); 

            } 
        });

    }
    public boolean Connection() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfoMob = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        NetworkInfo netInfoWifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if ((netInfoMob != null || netInfoWifi != null) && (netInfoMob.isConnectedOrConnecting() || netInfoWifi.isConnectedOrConnecting())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
        {
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
            {
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    mywebview.reload();
                    Log.v("INTERNET","RELOAD");

                    break;

            }
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```

When i click the menu "action_settings" the app is crashed just at the reload fucntion.I suspect that it has to do with the `mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()` or the `final WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);`

Any help or recomedations?

```
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce2948 that was originally bound here
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce2948 that was originally bound here
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-10 17:41:03.537: E/ActivityThread(669):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669): null
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce2948 that was originally bound here
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-10 17:41:03.557: E/StrictMode(669):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cecbf8 that was originally bound here
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cecbf8 that was originally bound here
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-10 17:41:03.657: E/ActivityThread(669):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669): null
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cecbf8 that was originally bound here
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-10 17:41:03.697: E/StrictMode(669):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace from LogCat.

Comment: Yeah,forgot to do it.Edited now.

Comment: try removing null , only Webview mywebview;

Answer (score 0):

Well,as i suspected

```
final WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

was the problem.

I changed it to

```
 mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

and worked like a charm.

Thanks anyway,hope it will help others.